# unitScale in TileMap Constructor

Tags: libgdx, tiled

How these tileMap Constructors actually work,especially with unitsacle ?

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(TiledMap map, float unitScale) ;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(TiledMap map, float unitScale, Batch batch); 
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(TiledMap map, Batch batch) ;
```

I created a tileMap and getting a hardTime to manage it.How Tilemap pixels varies with camera and viewport aspectratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get how tileMap Constructors actually work with unitscale

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps